# How to use namespace in the TCPDF?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, namespaces, tcpdf

I am trying to use TCPDF to print a pdf file in my php mvc project (model view controller), my problem is how to use `namespace` and `use` to make the tcpdf work.
i try this idea `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../TCPDF/TCPDF.php');` and it worked but i want to make it like this `use MYPROJECT\TCPDF\TCPDF;` and also i have been added this `namespace MYPROJECT\TCPDF` in all tcpdf php file and i get this erreur in the end class `TCPDF_FONTS` not found, although the TCPDF_FONTS file was added???
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search for `TCPDF_FONTS` in class `TCPDF_FONTS`. 
Then replace `TCPDF_FONTS` in function with `namespace\TCPDF_FONTS`. 
I did the same and it worked.

*Example:*

```
public static function UTF8ArrayToUniArray($ta, $isunicode=true) { <br>
    if ($isunicode) { <br>
         return array_map(array('**src\pdf\tcpdf\include\TCPDF_FONTS**', 
         'unichrUnicode'), $ta);
     } <br> 
    return array_map(array('**src\pdf\tcpdf\include\TCPDF_FONTS**', 'unichrASCII'), $ta); <br>
}
```